# Generating function - Partial fractions

Tags: generating-functions, partial-fractions

I was Reading a book about generating functions, and it said me to do this:

$$\frac{1 - 2x + 2x^2}{(1-x)^2(1-2x)} = \frac{A}{(1-x^2)} + \frac{B}{1-x}+\frac{C}{1-2x}$$

It says:

- `Multiply both sides by` $(1-x^2)$ so:

$$\frac{(1 - 2x + 2x^2)(1-x^2)}{(1-x)^2(1-2x)} = \frac{A(1-x^2)}{(1-x^2)} + \frac{B(1-x^2)}{1-x}+\frac{C(1-x^2)}{1-2x}$$

Then, it says to consider $x=1$, then $A = -1$. Well, I don't know why, since it will result in division by zero.

Comment: Cancel common factors in the numerator and denominator before inserting $\pm 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer it ONLY can be done assuming x does not equals 1

Comment: It's a rational function. $x$ is a variable. Only view as a point function after you're done with the algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @DanielFischer we only cancel things because we know that for any $x$, like in the function $\frac{x^2}{x}$, will result in $x$. Example: let $x=3$ then we have $\frac{3^2}{3}$ wich is in fact $3$, but when we let $x=0$ then we can't say that $\frac{0^2}{0}$ equals $0$

Comment: You mean $\dfrac{A}{(1-x)^2}$, not $\dfrac{A}{1-x^2}$

Comment: Otherwise the left side has a pole of order $2$ at $x=1$, while the right only has a pole of order $1$ there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m sure that it said to multiply both sides by $(1-x)^2$, not by $1-x^2$. When you do, you should have

$$\frac{1-2x+2x^2}{1-2x}=A+B(1-x)+\frac{C(1-x^2)}{1-2x}\;.$$

Now let $x=1$ and read off the value of $A$, since the last two terms on the righthand side are $0$.

**Added:** This is just a shortcut. What you’re really doing is finding the values of $A,B$, and $C$ that make the original equation an identity. After you put everything over the least common denominator, that equation is

$$\frac{1-2x+2x^2}{(1-x)^2(1-2x)}=\frac{A(1-2x)+B(1-x)(1-2x)+C(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^2(1-2x)}\;.\tag{1}$$

Two fractions with the same denominator are identically equal if and only if their numerators are identically equal:

$$1-2x+2x^2=A(1-2x)+B(1-x)(1-2x)+C(1-x)^2\;.\tag{2}$$

Substitute $x=1$ into $(1)$, and you immediately find that $-1=A$, or $A=-1$, and the suggested calculation is essentially the same thing.

Now it’s true that the fractions in $(1)$ are undefined at $x=1$ and $x=\frac12$, while the polynomials in $(2)$ are defined on all of $\Bbb R$. But making the polynomials in $(2)$ identically equal ensures that the fractions in $(1)$ will be equal wherever they are both defined, which is what we want, and making the polynomials identically easy is straightforward. If all else fails, we simply multiply out the righthand side of $(2)$ and equate coefficients to get a linear system of $3$ equations in the unknowns $A,B$, and $C$. Sometimes, however, as in this example, we can shortcut the process a bit by evaluating the polynomials at a point that knocks out all but one of the unknowns.

Comment: When you cancel the denominators? Shouldn't the new equation be undefined for the case when the denominator equals $0$? In other words, where $x = 1$.

Comment: @user108425: The **old** one was; the **new** one is not, which is what makes it useful. You are looking for the values of $A,B$, and $C$ that make the original equation an identity. These are precisely the ones that make $$1-2x+2x^2=A(1-2x)+B(1-x)(1-2x)+C(1-x)^2\;.$$ Clearly you can substitute $x=1$ into that to find that $1=-A$, or $A=-1$. Now look at the calculation that was suggested: it’s doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: So this is a trick that will make the old equation work? How did someone first think about this? Like: "let's try assuming that we can cancel the denominators, and then see if the values of $A$, $B$ and $C$ will work for the old equation". It was something like this? I need to understand the intuition behind this.

Comment: @user108425: It’s not really a trick; it’s just a shortcut to solving a particular system of equations. See if the addition to my answer helps.

Comment: You're my hero :)

Comment: @user108425: :-) Glad it helped!